# Symfony 3 overwrite FOS UserTemplate - but put the Views in my Bundle

Tags: symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

I write my own Bundle, in this bundle I need all the time the FOS User Bundle. So I put changed Forms and Entities in my Bundle. 
Finally I change the views from the FOS login and other pages.

I know that I have to put this in `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views`.

But my question - that I have this all in the future directly in my Bundle - is it possible to put this changed files in to my Bundle Folder? I tried under resource `src/MyBundle/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views` but it's not working.

Is this possible?

MF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a very standard way to override the directory structure in Symfony. It's a simple [yaml file entry](http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-the-templates-directory).

Whether this works perfectly with FOSUserBundle, I don't know. But it's a start. 
    Example:

```
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    paths:
      "%kernel.root_dir%/../templates": default
      "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/AppBundle/Resources/views": AppBundle
      "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/AdminBundle/Resources/views": AdminBundle
```